# How does adding big O notations works

Tags: asymptotics, arithmetic

can someone please explain how adding big O works.

i.e. $O(n^3)+O(n) = O(n^3)$

why does the answer turn out this way? is it because  $O(n^3)$ dominates the whole expression thus the answer is still $ O(n^3)$

Answer (score 5):

Big $O$ notation is the upper bound notation, so given two functions, such that $f\in O(g)$ ($f$ is upper bounded by $g$ to the linear constant from some point) the sum $O(f) + O(g) = O(g)$, and as $n \in O(n^3)$ (meaning $n$ too is bounded in the limit by some multiple of $n^3$) we have also that $O(n)+O(n^3)=O(n^3)$. It can be seen as a "domination" that you refer in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The formal definition for equalities which contain $\;O(\cdot)\;$ and related notations, is that these notations are sets, and that such an equality holds if it holds *for every* function in each left hand side set, and for *some* function in each right hand side set.

*(Anyone: Feel free to insert a reference; I don't have one at hand.)*

Therefore $$
O(n^3)+O(n) = O(n^3)
$$ is formally an abbreviation for $$
\langle \forall f,g : f \in O(n^3) \land g \in O(n) : \langle \exists h : h \in O(n^3) : \langle \forall n :: f(n) + g(n) = h(n) \rangle \rangle \rangle
$$  (I won't go into the proof of this statement here; the first answer should help you there.)

Note how this general definition applies to the special case of $$
f(n) = O(g(n))
$$ where it gives us $$
\langle \exists h : h \in O(g(n)) : \langle \forall n :: f(n) = h(n) \rangle \rangle
$$ which can quicky be simplified to the usual $$
f \in O(g(n))
$$

Answer (score 0):

To show the equality $O(n^3)+O(n)=O(n^3)$, which are two sets, we can show their mutual inclusion - they are two forms of recording the one and same set. Formally, the left side is a subset of right side and reverse:

$O(n^3)+O(n) \subseteq O(n^3)$  and  $O(n^3) \subseteq O(n^3)+O(n)  $.

If "dominance" is understood as inequality $n \leqslant n^3$, then we can say that, yes, $n^3$ "dominates" $n$.