# What does the sign "$=$" exact meanings?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, asymptotics

How can I understand the sign "$=$" from the following expression:

$$\mathcal{o}f((x))=\mathcal{o}f((x))+\mathcal{o}f((x));$$
$$\mathcal{o}(kf((x)))=\mathcal{o}(f(x));$$
$$t\mathcal{o}(f((x)))=\mathcal{o}(f(x)).$$
(  $k$ and $t$ are constants,$\mathcal{o}$ is little $o$  Notation )

Someone say the sign "$=$ " only means "$\subseteq$ " ; others confirm" the sign "$=$"has the same meaning as the equivalence of two sets (i.e.Let two sets $A,B$:$A=B\Leftrightarrow  A$$\subseteq $$B$ and $A$$\supseteq $$B$ )."But what does the sign "$=$" exact meaning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for equals signs with big-O and little-o?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86076/what-are-the-rules-for-equals-signs-with-big-o-and-little-o)

Comment: @JMoravitz:According to your useful link,the sign "$=$" only means "$\subseteq$".

Comment: If the abuse bothers you and you want to try to help put an end to it, another common notation I have seen is $\asymp$ written as \asymp.

Comment: @JMoravitz To mean...what? I have only seen that notation used for logarithmic equivalence.

Comment: Related/duplicate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/514263/11994.  Personally I think my answer there is the simplest explanation I've seen for this notation, and a longer more precise version is in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/86088/11994.

Answer (score 3):

It should be read as a $\subseteq$, inclusion only in the one direction.

Taken from Concrete Mathematics by R. Graham

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have never liked this abuse of notation, and prefer to write e.g. $f(n) \in \mathcal O(n^2)$.